# how to convert property of class to array with retrolambda

Tags: android, retrolambda

Im using retrolambda in Android.

I have one class like below code(Java).

`public class ContactListViewModel {
    public String DisplayName;
    public String PhoneNumber;
}`

And there is a method that returns value back like  `ArrayList<ContactListViewModel>`

I want to only select `PhoneNumber` property and i want to it is convert to array.

android :

```
ArrayList<ContactListViewModel> contactList = contactListService.GetContactList(getContext().getContentResolver());
    ArrayList<List> phoneList = contactList.stream().Select(l->l.PhoneNumber).ToArray();
```

Above how can i do?

like c#

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ContactListViewModel> p = new List<ContactListViewModel>();
        var phoneNumberArr = p.Select(l => l.PhoneNumber).ToArray();
    }
}
public class ContactListViewModel
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i found

```
List<String> phoneList =  contactList.stream().map(arr->arr.PhoneNumber).collect(Collectors.toList());
```